# Upload and share file to Google Drive from Android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-oauth

My app should ask user to use its Google account and upload a file to its Google Drive storage. Also I need have a possibility to share this file to some people by emails.

So I'm trying use Google Drive SDK instead Google Drive Android API, because the last one can only upload to AppFolder which can't be shared. But I can't figure out how to use Google Drive SDK with Google OAuth 2.0 correctly. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: While the initial API only supported AppFolder, the Google Drive Android API now does support creating/writing files anywhere on the user's Google Drive as per [Authorizing the Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api) (`Drive.SCOPE_FILE`)

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm trying using Google APIs Java Client, and it seems ok, but when I call `service.files().insert(…)` the error occured: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException